# my css not working correctly not changing back ground?

Tags: html, css, background-image

hi i am trying to change back ground on the menu i created but it is not using image in the back groung at normal condition and on mouse hover my code is,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

<style type="text/css">

html{

font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

color:#333;

padding:0;

margin:0;}



.listmenu ul {

margin: 0 0 5px 0;

padding: 0 0 2px 0;

list-style-type: none;

width:185px;}



.listmenu li a {

color: #333;

display: block;

border-left:3px solid #666;

border-right:3px solid #666;

height: 16px;

padding: 4px 0 4px 14px;

text-decoration: none;

font-weight:bold;

background-image:  url('menu5.gif')}



.listmenu li a:hover {

background: url(images/bg.jpg) ;

color:#000000;}

</style>

<div class="listmenu">

<ul>

    <li><a href="#">General</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Add Location</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Host</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Host Groups</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Summary</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Problems</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Services(Unhandled)</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Host(Unhandled)</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Availability</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Trends</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Alerts</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Events Logs</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Sysytem</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Down time</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Process info</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Scheduling Queue</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Configuration</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

hopes to listen from you soon thanks in advance .

Comment: close background-image:  url('menu5.gif') -> background-image:  url('menu5.gif');

Comment: i did it but it is not working

Comment: everything works for me.. maybe image dir is not correct? or you are running web of linux .gif and .GIF for linux is a huge difference

Comment: may be your image url path is wrong

Comment: is your path correct? Keep in mind that for css, the path is relative to the css file, not to the current browser path.  Try opening this file from your browser, to check for 404.  If all else fails, open the firebug net tab and check where it loads the image.  A 200 would be the required reply, but you'll probably get something else.

Comment: thanks all of you i have got answer that is "background:url("images/menu5.gif") no-repeat 0 0 ;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is background url
2. is background repeat
3. is background position

background:url("images/menu5.gif") no-repeat 0 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

Should be "background-image" instead of just "background".

"background" is a shorthand notation which requires position information as well.

```
.listmenu li a:hover {

    background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');

    color:#000000;}
```

UPDATE: Apparently I am not correct.  Looks like you can specify *one or more* properties for `background`.  I tested and either method works in both Firefox 11.0 and IE 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

May be your URL is wrong because

```
On normal state the URL is url('menu5.gif');

On hover state the URL is url('images/menu5.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not giving the exact path to your **anchor & hover** background images please give the exact path to them than they will call the exactly as you want.

see the demo i have given the exact path of the background image on **anchor & hover** its working fine:-

http://jsbin.com/uzojaj/4/edit

And please check it your **.listmenu li a**, .**listmenu li a:hover** give the correct to images path to it....